# Hibernate query LIKE clause, but with space separating lookup prefix and wildcard

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a Hibernate query that has a prefix to find, which looks like:

```
SELECT ... WHERE PRODUCT_ID LIKE ?
```

The `PRODUCT_ID` has a format that looks like:

```
ABC123 Brown Desk
ABC1 Desk Set
DE84 Bar Stool
83UIK Spoon
```

Currently, the prepared statement value looks like (assuming `productId` is passed in as an argument):

```
productId%
```

Which means that for a queried ID `ABC1`, it would return **two** results from the above list:

```
ABC123 Brown Desk
ABC1 Desk Set
```

**My question:** How can I include the space in the lookup so that the query is for a **specific** product, and not just the prefix?

I tried:

```
'productId %'
```

But it doesn't return any results at all. How can I tell Hibernate that I want to do a lookup for `productId[SINGLE SPACE]%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `CONCAT` instead of `'productId %'` or `'? %'` :

```
SELECT ... WHERE PRODUCT_ID LIKE CONCAT(?, ' %')
//------------------------------------------^^
```

Or you can concatinate the `productId` with a space in the end, before you send it to the query :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT ... WHERE PRODUCT_ID LIKE ?");
query.setParameter(1, productId + " %");
//---------------------------------^^
```